# complain mysql queries to single query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 Queries

```
SELECT * FROM `admin_sprints` 
where CURDATE() < `sprint_start_date` and 
      CURDATE() <`sprint_end_date` - retuen type  as future

SELECT * FROM `admin_sprints` 
where CURDATE() > `sprint_start_date` and 
      CURDATE() >`sprint_end_date` - retuen type  as past

SELECT * FROM `admin_sprints` 
where CURDATE() between `sprint_start_date` and 
     `sprint_end_date` - retuen type  as current
```

i tried to combine this to single queries

So i tried

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    admin_sprints
ORDER BY (CASE
    WHEN sprint_start_date` and CURDATE() <`sprint_end_date`  THEN future
    ELSE admin_sprints` where CURDATE() > `sprint_start_date` and CURDATE() >`sprint_end_date then over
  ELSE current
END); 

admin_sprints
---------------|------------|-----------------|-----------------------
sprint_id      |sprint_name  |sprint_start_date|     sprint_end_date  |
1                Sprint1        2018-11-01          2018-11-13
2                sprint2          2018-11-14         2018-11-23
3                sprint 3        2018-11-24          2018-11-130
```

expected output

```
sprint_id   sprint_name       type
    1        Sprint1            over
    2        Sprint2            Active
    3         Sprint3           future
```

I don't know method is correct or not.Bad luck it's not working.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @fa06 i have update my question please help me

Comment: You need to take your CASE statement out of order by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `CASE..WHEN` statements in your `SELECT` clause, to determine the `type` accordingly. Try:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE WHEN sprint_start_date < CURDATE() AND 
              sprint_end_date < CURDATE() 
           THEN 'over'
         WHEN CURDATE() BETWEEN sprint_start_date AND 
                                sprint_end_date 
           THEN 'active'
         ELSE 'future'
    END AS type
FROM
    admin_sprints
```